# Turn Xlsxwriter sheet into Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I have a DataFrame read from an excel sheet in which I've made a few new columns to using Xlsxwriter. Now I need to filter this new set of data using the new column I created in Xlsxwriter (which is a date column btw). Is there a way to turn this new worksheet into a dataframe again so I can filter the new column? I'll try to provide any useful code:

```
export = "files/extract.xlsx"
future_days = 12
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('files/new_report-%s.xlsx' % (date.today()), engine ='xlsxwriter')
workbook = writer.book
df = pd.read_excel(export)
df.to_excel(writer, 'Full Log', index=False)
log_sheet = writer.sheets['Full Log']

new_headers = ('todays date', 'Milestone Date')
log_sheet.write_row('CW1', new_headers)

# This for loop just writes in the formula for my new columns on every line
        for row_num in range(2, len(df.index)+2):
            log_sheet.write_formula('CX' + str(row_num),'=IF(AND($BS{0}>1/1/1990,$BT{0}<>"Yes"),IF($BS{0}<=$CW{0},$BS{0},"Date In Future"),IF(AND($BW{0}>1/1/1990,$BX{0}<>"Yes"),IF($BW{0}<=CW{0},$BW{0},"Date In Future"),IF(AND($CA{0}>1/1/1990,$CCW{0}<>"Yes"),IF($CA{0}<=CW{0},$CA{0},"Date In Future"),IF(AND($CE{0}>1/1/1990,$CF{0}<>"Yes"),IF($CE{0}<CW{0},$CE{0},"Date In Future"),IF(AND($CI{0}>1/1/1990,$CJ{0}<>"Yes"),IF($CI{0}<CW{0},$CI{0},"Date In Future"),IF(AND($CM{0}>1/1/1990,$CN{0}<>"Yes"),IF($CM{0}<CW{0},$CM{0},"Date In Future"),"No Date"))))))'.format(row_num))
            log_sheet.write_formula('CW' + str(row_num), '=TODAY()+' + str(future_days))
            log_sheet.write_formula('CY' + str(row_num), '=IF(AND(AI{0}>DATEVALUE("1/1/1900"), AH{0}>DATEVALUE("1/1/1900"),A{0}<>"Test",A{0}<>"Dummy Test"),NETWORKDAYS(AH{0},AI{0}-1),"Test")'.format(row_num))
```

So now that's all done I need to filter this "full log" sheet so it only gets data where the values in the new milestone date column have passed the date of today. I've used Xlsxwriters Autofilter for this but I don't like it as it doesn't actually apply the filter. just sets it.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the save function on the writer then load the file into a new dataframe

```
writer.save()
df2 = pd.read_excel('Full Log')
```

Comment: I get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Full Log'
` Are you sure it's possible to read a single created worksheet?